# Finding integer solutions to $n=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations

Is there anything known how to find integer solutions to 
$$n=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$
where $n$ is a natural number $\neq 3,6 \mod 9$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Notice that 
$$n = \det \left(\begin{array}{rrr}a & b & c \\c & a & b \\b & c & a\end{array}\right) $$
where the matrix on the right hand side is the group matrix of the cyclic group $C_3$ as defined by Dedekind.

Given a solution $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ to the equation above, $n$ a natural number given, we can find infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$n = u^3+v^3+w^3-3uvw$$

where 
$$u = \frac{9 \, a t^{3} + 9 \, b t^{3} + 9 \, c t^{3} + 9 \, a t^{2} + 9 \, b t^{2} + 9 \, c t^{2} + 3 \, a t + 3 \, b t + 3 \, c t + a}{3 \, t + 1}$$

$$v = \frac{9 \, a t^{3} + 9 \, b t^{3} + 9 \, c t^{3} + 9 \, a t^{2} + 9 \, b t^{2} + 9 \, c t^{2} + 3 \, a t + 3 \, b t + 3 \, c t + b}{3 \, t + 1}$$

$$w = \frac{9 \, a t^{3} + 9 \, b t^{3} + 9 \, c t^{3} + 9 \, a t^{2} + 9 \, b t^{2} + 9 \, c t^{2} + 3 \, a t + 3 \, b t + 3 \, c t + c}{3 \, t + 1}$$

For a construction of these solutions, see the related question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715969/does-the-polynomial-r3s3t3-3rst-1-have-rational-roots

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the norm form for the algebra $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 1)$, which should certainly make some of the structure of the solutions clearer. In particular, this makes clear that the third cyclotomic field will play a role in understanding the solutions.

Comment: This reminds me of how $(28a^3+b^3)^3=(18a^3+2b^3)^3+(19a^3+b^3)^3+(21a^3-b^3)^3+3(10a^2b)^3$

Comment: One approach would be to factor $n$ and then set the variable $a+b+c$ to equal a divisor, so the quadratic term would be another divisor. This reduces the problem to solving a quadratic form in two variables.  The quadratic form, following Daniel's comments, should be the norm form of $\mathbb Q(\mu_3)$, up to mod $3$ adjustments, so you can look at prime factors congruent to $1$ mod $3$ and find the corresponding ideals.

Comment: @DanielLoughran: Where can I read about the norm form? Wikipedia is very sparse for this topic.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: What I mean is that you can define the norm of any finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $K$, and not just number fields. Then once you choose a basis for $K$, the norm is given by a homogenous polynomial of degree $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$. The polynomial you get in your case is the one given by the basis $1,x,x^2$ of the algebra I wrote down. This allows you to see immediately for example if $n$ and $m$ are representable, then so is $nm$, as a product of norms is a norm.

Comment: If you just want to find one representation for each
$n \not\equiv \pm 3 \bmod 9$,
see the solution of problem A1 in the most recent (2019) Putnam exam.
https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2019s.pdf

Comment: At the risk of pointing out what might be obvious (number theory is not something I know much about), the google search [Diophantine + "ternary cubic form"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Diophantine+%22ternary+cubic+form%22) might be useful, as well as appropriate sections of Dickson's 3-volume treatise [**History of the Theory of Numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Theory_of_Numbers).

Comment: It is known there is the solution for $n=t^k.$  
For instance, solution for $k=2$ is below.  
$(a,b,c,t)=(2pr+q^2,2pq+r^2,p^2+2qr,q^3-3qpr+p^3+r^3)$  
$p,q,r$ are arbitrary.

Comment: Another link to solutions of 2019 Putnam A1: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/Putnam/2019/Putsol2019A.pdf

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson for th link.

Comment: Thanks @NoamD.Elkies for the link.